# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg' terminal not working

Tags: command-line, apt

I have installed Matlab but when it installed I am not able to do anything with the terminal it is showing the following error:

```
~$ pip install flask
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 5, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt install --reinstall python3-apt
```

This reinstalls apt_pkg, and fixes the error of it not being present in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages.

Comment: While this command might work, please consider adding an explanation of what does this command do, and why you've suggested using it. This would really help OP and any other future users stumbling upon this answer.